# In which poem(s) in Day by Day does Robert Lowell describe erectile dysfunction?

Tags: poetry, robert-lowell

[Robert Lowell's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Lowell) states that Helen Vendler, in contrast to certain other critics, praised Lowell's final publication, ***Day by Day***, especially because of:

> his descriptions of **impotence**, depression, and old age.

Of course, the word *impotence* can mean several things, but the context strongly suggests the sense of *erectile dysfunction* to my mind. (Or perhaps I just need to be psychoanalysed!) And, for what it's worth, whoever wrote that portion of the Wikipedia page agrees with me: the word *impotence* is hyperlinked to the erectile dysfunction page.

Is erectile dysfunction discussed in *Day by Day*? And, if so, in which poems?

Comment: *Day by Day* is available to borrow at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/daybyday00lowe/page/n5/mode/2up), if you fancy having an account to read it online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking through *Day by Day*, I found two poems that might be talking about impotence, although neither of them mentions it explicitly.

In *Ear of Corn*, about an old wine baron, the following lines at least show the inability of the subject to make young women be attracted to him.

> someone's young wife is on his right—
> ...
> She cannot cure his hallucination
> he can bribe or stare
> any woman he wants into orgasm...
> He fills her ear
> with his old sexual gramophone.
> Like belief,
> he makes nothing happen.

And *The Downlook* is also suggestive of impotence. It even contains the word (although possibly in another context, unless "two-way traffic" is a metaphor for sexual intercourse, which I suspect it is).  Here are what I think are the most suggestive lines from this poem.

> ...
> nothing lovelier than waking to find
> another breathing body in my bed ...
> glowshadow halfcovered with dayclothes like my own,
> caught in my arms.
>
> Last summer nothing dared impede
> the flow of the body's thousand rivulets of welcome ...
> winding effortlessly, yet with ambiguous invention—
> safety in nearness.
>
> Now the downlook, the downlook—small fuss,
> ...
> each miss must be a mile
> if one risk the narrow two-lane highway.
>
> It's impotence and impertinence to ask directions,
> while staring right and left in two-way traffic.
> ...
> Ah, loved perhaps before I knew you,
> others have been lost like this,
> yet found foothold
> by winning the dolphin from the humming water.
> ...

Robert Lowell suffered episodes of depression for much of his life. However, depression can cause impotence, and I believe that this is indeed a subtext here.
*The Downlook* seems to be primarily about depression (which is also one of the definitions of the word *downlook*). And this is indeed how Lowell used the word: Google finds:

> In a letter to Blair Clark, Lowell speaks of the “downlook” as an inward feeling of depression (the aftermath of manic attack)

Comment: **Great answer, exactly what I was looking for.** On a point of pedantry: I think it's best to put the titles of **volumes of poetry** in italics, and the titles of **individual poems** in quotation marks. But no doubt you can find a dozen style guides stating the opposite.